# How do I find a certain word in the text file and send the value that would be the word?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./test.txt', function(error, data) {
  if (!error) {
    data = data.toString(); 

    const firstLine = data.split('\n')[0];

    console.log(`${firstLine}`)
  }
});
```

Imagine that in file `test.txt` you have the following words:

```
Hello\nHi\nTest
```

I want to find word Hi and return that value in `${firstLine}`.

Comment: Do you need to find one word or a list of words?

Comment: The specific word

Comment: Use a regular expression. Try `data.match(new RegExp("\\b" + your_word_here + "\\b")`. And if you need to find the word `Hi` (which is in the second line) then what do you mean by __I want to find word Hi and return that value in ${firstLine}__ and what is the point of that __firstline__ constant?

Comment: This means that when executing the code it will find the word that is on the first line of the text file

Each word is a line, so the Hello is the first and so on

When I say a specific word, I mean, instead of just finding the first line, I mean finding any line

So instead of giving the value of **Hello** I want the value of **Test** for example

Comment: That **\n** means skipping a line

Comment: Here's an example:

const abc = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt').toString('utf-8').includes('Hi') ? 'Yes' : 'No'

It will see if there is word **Hi** in the text file, if there is, it will return as **Yes**

But since I don't know otherwise I want it to return the specific word